# Ensuring with XML schema (XSD) uniqueness of elements and attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to ensure that my "number" element content and "playId" attribute is unique on the same level. I have read other posts but I'm unable to find out the trick to do it.

Here my example XML with the corresponding schema:

```
<tic:tickets xmlns:tic="http://www.ti.bfh.ch/i1p/akz/schema/ticket2">
    <tic:ticket ticketId="0">
        <tic:plays>
            <tic:play playId="0">
                <tic:numbers>
                    <tic:number>1</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>2</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>3</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>4</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>5</tic:number>
                </tic:numbers>
                <tic:stars>
                    <tic:star>1</tic:star>
                    <tic:star>2</tic:star>
                </tic:stars>
            </tic:play>
            <tic:play playId="0">
                <tic:numbers>
                    <tic:number>50</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>50</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>50</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>50</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>50</tic:number>
                </tic:numbers>
                <tic:stars>
                    <tic:star>11</tic:star>
                    <tic:star>11</tic:star>
                </tic:stars>
            </tic:play>
        </tic:plays>
        <tic:superStars>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">12AB</tic:superStar>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">12AB</tic:superStar>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">12AB</tic:superStar>
            <tic:superStar selected="true">12AB</tic:superStar>
        </tic:superStars>
        <tic:validity>2</tic:validity>
        <tic:dateTime>2007-10-26T08:36:28</tic:dateTime>
    </tic:ticket>
    <tic:ticket ticketId="0">
        <tic:plays>
            <tic:play playId="100">
                <tic:numbers>
                    <tic:number>1</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>1</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>3</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>4</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>5</tic:number>
                </tic:numbers>
                <tic:stars>
                    <tic:star>11</tic:star>
                    <tic:star>11</tic:star>
                </tic:stars>
            </tic:play>
        </tic:plays>
        <tic:superStars>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">12AB</tic:superStar>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">12AB</tic:superStar>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">12AB</tic:superStar>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">12AB</tic:superStar>
        </tic:superStars>
        <tic:validity>6</tic:validity>
        <tic:dateTime>2007-10-26T08:36:28</tic:dateTime>
    </tic:ticket>
</tic:tickets>
```

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tic="http://www.ti.bfh.ch/i1p/akz/schema/ticket2"
           targetNamespace="http://www.ti.bfh.ch/i1p/akz/schema/ticket2" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="tickets">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="ticket">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:complexContent>
                            <xs:extension base="tic:ticketType">
                                <xs:attribute name="ticketId" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:complexContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="uniqueTicketId">
                        <xs:selector xpath="ticket"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@ticketId"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>


    <xs:complexType name="ticketType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="plays">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="7" minOccurs="1">
                        <xs:element name="play">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="numbers">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="5" minOccurs="5">
                                                <xs:element name="number" type="tic:numberType"/>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:unique name="uniqueNumber">
                                            <xs:selector xpath="number"/>
                                            <xs:field xpath="."/>
                                        </xs:unique>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="stars">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="2">
                                                <xs:element name="star" type="tic:starType"/>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:unique name="uniqueStar">
                                            <xs:selector xpath="star"/>
                                            <xs:field xpath="."/>
                                        </xs:unique>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="playId" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                            <xs:unique name="uniquePlayId">
                                <xs:selector xpath="play"/>
                                <xs:field xpath="@playId"/>
                            </xs:unique>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="superStars">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="4" minOccurs="4">
                        <xs:element name="superStar">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="tic:superStarType">
                                        <xs:attribute default="false" name="selected"
                                                      type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:unique name="uniqueSuperStar">
                    <xs:selector xpath="superStar"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="."/>
                </xs:unique>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="validity" type="tic:validityType"/>
            <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="validityType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="6"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="8"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="numberType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="50"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="starType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="11"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="superStarType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

I'm thankful for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared the uniqueness constraints in the wrong context. If you want unique `@playId` attributes for each `play` element, that has to be declared in the parent's (`plays`) context. I wouldn't make sense to declare it in the context of `play` itself, since you couldn't have duplicate attributes anyway. So you should make the changes below:

```
<xs:element name="plays">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="7" minOccurs="1">
            <xs:element name="play">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>...</xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="playId" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
                <!-- move from here... -->
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniquePlayId"> <!-- ... to here -->
        <xs:selector xpath="tic:play"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@playId"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

And do the same with `ticketId`, since it is also in the wrong context.

There is one more problem: your XPath selectors are not *qualified*. There is no default namespace in XPath. If the selector is not qualified it will be treated as belonging to no-namespace, and will not match anything. You need to qualify all of your `xpath` element selectors: `tic:play`, `tic:superStar`, `tic:number`, etc.

See also: [Making Element Values Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718852/making-element-values-unique/23718917#23718917)

Answer (score 0):

@helderdarocha
Thank you very much!
I have played around with the level at which I inserted the `<xs:unique>`-statement.

That wasn't my major problem but what I didn't understand was the problem with the unqualified selector within the statement! Now I understand the background. Perfect ^^!

Here is the corrected and working version of schema/xml:

XML:

```
<tic:tickets xmlns:tic="http://www.ti.bfh.ch/i1p/akz/schema/tickets">
    <tic:ticket ticketId="0">
        <tic:plays>
            <tic:play playId="0">
                <tic:numbers>
                    <tic:number>1</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>2</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>3</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>49</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>50</tic:number>
                </tic:numbers>
                <tic:stars>
                    <tic:star>1</tic:star>
                    <tic:star>11</tic:star>
                </tic:stars>
            </tic:play>
            <tic:play playId="1">
                <tic:numbers>
                    <tic:number>1</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>2</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>3</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>49</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>50</tic:number>
                </tic:numbers>
                <tic:stars>
                    <tic:star>1</tic:star>
                    <tic:star>11</tic:star>
                </tic:stars>
            </tic:play>
        </tic:plays>
        <tic:superStars>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">AB01</tic:superStar>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">AB02</tic:superStar>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">AB03</tic:superStar>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">AB04</tic:superStar>
        </tic:superStars>
        <tic:validity>1</tic:validity>
        <tic:dateTime>2014-05-20T18:36:28</tic:dateTime>
    </tic:ticket>
    <tic:ticket ticketId="1">
        <tic:plays>
            <tic:play playId="0">
                <tic:numbers>
                    <tic:number>1</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>2</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>3</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>49</tic:number>
                    <tic:number>50</tic:number>
                </tic:numbers>
                <tic:stars>
                    <tic:star>1</tic:star>
                    <tic:star>11</tic:star>
                </tic:stars>
            </tic:play>
        </tic:plays>
        <tic:superStars>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">AB01</tic:superStar>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">AB02</tic:superStar>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">AB03</tic:superStar>
            <tic:superStar selected="false">AB04</tic:superStar>
        </tic:superStars>
        <tic:validity>6</tic:validity>
        <tic:dateTime>2014-05-19T09:44:53</tic:dateTime>
    </tic:ticket>
</tic:tickets>
```

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tic="http://www.ti.bfh.ch/i1p/akz/schema/tickets"
           targetNamespace="http://www.ti.bfh.ch/i1p/akz/schema/tickets" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="tickets">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="ticket">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:complexContent>
                            <xs:extension base="tic:ticketType">
                                <xs:attribute name="ticketId" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:complexContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="uniqueTicketId">
            <xs:selector xpath="tic:ticket"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@ticketId"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>


    <xs:complexType name="ticketType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="plays">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="7" minOccurs="1">
                        <xs:element name="play">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="numbers">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="5" minOccurs="5">
                                                <xs:element name="number" type="tic:numberType"/>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:unique name="uniqueNumber">
                                            <xs:selector xpath="tic:number"/>
                                            <xs:field xpath="."/>
                                        </xs:unique>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="stars">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="2">
                                                <xs:element name="star" type="tic:starType"/>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:unique name="uniqueStar">
                                            <xs:selector xpath="tic:star"/>
                                            <xs:field xpath="."/>
                                        </xs:unique>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="playId" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:unique name="uniquePlayId">
                    <xs:selector xpath="tic:play"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="@playId"/>
                </xs:unique>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="superStars">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="4" minOccurs="4">
                        <xs:element name="superStar">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="tic:superStarType">
                                        <xs:attribute default="false" name="selected"
                                                      type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:unique name="uniqueSuperStar">
                    <xs:selector xpath="tic:superStar"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="."/>
                </xs:unique>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="validity" type="tic:validityType"/>
            <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="validityType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="6"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="8"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="numberType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="50"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="starType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="11"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="superStarType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```